# converting a multidimensional array to a single dimension array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

After going through similar questions i couldn't find matching my scenario.
I have $artists_temp array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [post_title] => Junoon
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 135
            [post_title] => Linkin Park
        )

)
```

I have done with code to make the array like

```
Array
(
    [109] => Junoon
    [Junoon] => 
    [135] => Linkin Park
    [Linkin Park] => 
)
```

Whats required is like

```
Array
(
    [109] => Junoon
    [135] => Linkin Park
)
```

Here is the code

```
$artists_temp = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
$artists = array();
foreach ($artists_temp as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $artists[$v] = next($value);
        //unset(next($value)) This doesn't work.
    }
}
print_r($artists);
```

Comment: You could add `break;` on the line after `$artists[$v] = `.

Comment: @cpilko Thanks man that did the work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do

```
$artists = array();

foreach ($artists_temp as $array) {
    $artists[$array['ID']] = $array['post_title'];
}
```

Comment: cant wait 1 minute to accept this :) Works like a charm

Comment: Glad I could be of service! :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php):

```
$artists = array_column($artists_temp, 'post_title', 'ID');
```

Since you are using WordPress check out: [wp_list_pluck()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck):

```
$artists = wp_list_pluck($artists_temp, 'post_title', 'ID');
```

Comment: this is informative really. But as i am creating a wordpress plugin not all users have 5.5

Comment: I hate WordPress, but a quick search turned-up http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck

Comment: accepted the below answer but thanks for sharing the nice function array_column is so cool !

Comment: So you didn't like the WP function that does exactly what you want?

Comment: I  was more concerned about the solution in terms of programming.